# How do i download prawn pdf file while using form submit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

```
def index
    @forms = Form.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
    end
  end
    def submit
        respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf {render  }

    end
    end

submit.pdf.prawn file
pdf.text "successfully submitted"
```

Comment: need more information than only past your code

Comment: For example - tell us what happens when you run this code - do you get a error message? Have you tried anything else? How did that work out? Do you know which part of the code is causing trouble for you? Are you missing a concept you'd like us to help outline for you?

Answer (score 10):

It is possible for Prawn to generate and return the PDF without having to to save locally...

```
def submit
  send_data(generate_pdf, :filename => "output.pdf", :type => "application/pdf") 
end

private 
def generate_pdf
    Prawn::Document.new do
        text "Hello Stackoverflow"
    end.render 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use prawn to generate a pdf that's saved somewhere in your /public folder, like:

```
Prawn::Document.generate("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/myfile.pdf")
```

Then just use your controller to redirect users to that location:

```
redirect_to '/pdfs/myfile.pdf'
```

Comment: Use prawn to generate a pdf that's saved somewhere in your /public folder, like:

Prawn::Document.generate("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/pdfs/myfile.pdf")
Then just use your controller to redirect users to that location:

redirect_to '/pdfs/myfile.pdf'

Comment: Unknown action

No action responded to show. Actions: current_user, current_user_session, generate, index, permission_denied, travel_log, and unauthorised_url

Comment: The problem with this answer is that if the app is served by multiple servers, the server that responded to the redirect may not be the one that has '/pdfs/myfile.pdf' so the user would get a 404.